# How to become a pro at .Net Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

I want to be a pro in Serialization in .Net. I want to know all the concepts inside out, the purpose of serialization, different mechanisms available, scenarios where default serialization fails, and custom serialization is needed, how custom serialization can be implemented.

This is turning out to be a very important skill, and lack of it is hurting me.

Please point me to any resources/guides/videos/tutorials that are relevant.

Comment: The first thing to learn about serialization is that the built in `BinaryFormatter` and `XmlSerializer` are rarely the right choice.

Answer (score 2):

Starting point here:

- [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7ay27kt9.aspx) at MSDN

You can try to implement your own custom serialization mechanism just for practice, optimized for a particular scenario / problem. This way you'll become familiar with .NET Serialization internals.

- [Custom Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ty01x675.aspx) at MSDN

As [Xaisoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33690) mentioned, read, code, read, code ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a search on google for .NET Serialization and find a ton of resources.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to consider other serialization techniques that are far more famous that .NET Serialization.  [Google's ProtoBuffer](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html), [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) is couple of them.